# How to overcome this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'instancemethod'"

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, instance-method

I'm working with pandas and i just came across this error, So basically i concated several dataframes to make one and i took the 'mean' and 'std' of each column using the following command

```
df = pd.concat(df_all)
df = df.groupby('wave').agg(['mean','std']).reset_index()

        wave       num             stlines                 fwhm            
                  mean       std      mean        std      mean       std   
0    4050.32  2.700565  1.036630  0.285702   0.007247  0.073511  0.002398   
1    4208.98  4.632768  0.959788  0.484906   0.007137  0.086225  0.002070   
2    4374.94  8.576271  1.299520  0.714421   0.003106  0.113164  0.001426   
3    4379.74  4.248588  3.469888  0.310619   0.004290  0.091814  0.002183   
4    4398.01  8.632768  3.628431  0.502670   0.007020  0.094771  0.005925
```

Now when i tried to plot this data

```
mean = df['fwhm']['mean']
std  = df['fwhm']['std']

plt.errorbar(df.wave,mean, yerr = std ,fmt='o', label='original data')
```

Then i got this error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'instancemethod'**

So when i checked the type of `std` `type(df['fwhm']['mean'])` then it says it's an `instancemethod`.

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Hi! I try your code on my example data and it works. I think you have trouble with code above groupby. Try to add simple data of "df_all" and write more about code above. You TypeError mean you have problem with type, but I think not in this data example.

Comment: Hi ana, yep you're right.!  The problem was in the above lines of the code but i solved the problem on my own. @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia